# What is the iOS equivalent of Michael Hartl's Rails 3 Tutorial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios

I'm a newbie programmer and I've been reading Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial. I'm enjoying the book very much. It's easy to follow and doesn't assume I know much.

I'd also like to learn to code iOS apps (both iPhone and iPad) and would appreciate any recommendations on books or courses that could help me to do so.

Thanks in advance for the assistance!

Eddie

Comment: Ruby and Rails are elegant and easy to learn.  iOS programming (Objective C, Cocoa Touch, XCode, etc) is an ugly, obtuse morass that's a huge pain to deal with.

Not an answer to your question (which is why I'm just leaving a comment) but maybe be prepared to adjust your expectations.  Last tutorial I saw for writing "hello world" was like 11 printed pages...

Comment: I know iOS, but I don't know Michael Hartl's tutorial. Maybe if you explained what you like about it or how it's organized you might get more useful responses here.

Comment: Thanks @benzado. Basically an iOS tutorial that's easy to follow and doesn't assume I have anything beyond very basic programming knowledge. I've only been coding (if you can call it that) for less than a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 1):

There is this course: http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/cs193p-student-final-projects/id395605774?i=90218598

It is a lecture series from Stanford, available for free via iTunes. It looks pretty good. It assumes some level of OO skills, and I'd say some basic C experience would also help, but it assumes no knowledge of iOS development.

An alternative that costs a little bit is the TekPub series: http://shop.tekpub.com/products/iphone It's $25 for that series (unless you have a subscription of course), but I'd say it was pretty good value for money.

Don't forget there are a lot of good and free doc on the Apple developer website too.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet - if not only bet - is the iOS Programming Course on iTunes shared by Stanford University. It's free and the professors are Apple developers. Every semester features a different lead professor that has a different view on iOS programming. At the time of this answer, Paul Hegarty's version of course is on iTunesU.